# jar and classpath wildcards

Tags: java, jar, directory, classpath, wildcard

I want to have multiple classpath directories specified for a standalone java application under Win 7 with java 7 both 64bit.

The directory structure should be as follows

```
-app
|-lib
|-dynamicLib
|app.jar
```

the lib folder contains dependecies that are referenced directly in the manifest. everything in `dynamicLib` should be loaded as well.

I tried the following:

adding `dynamicLib\*` to the manifests classpath

adding `dynamicLib` to the commandline like this

```
java -cp "dynamicLib\*";app.jar my.mainclass
```

the latter with and without quotes, absolute and relative paths, invertes slash etc. But both did not work.

So, how do you add a wildcard directory to an existing classpath when executing a jar?

Comment: does it work without the wildcard?

Comment: @yair no it doesn't, hm thats strange. Thanks

Comment: if dynamiclib is a directory that contains .class files then the command is java -cp "dynamicLib;app.jar" my.mainclass

Comment: have you tried forward slash instead of the backslash? I guess that the backslash is interpreted as an escape character, so you should use \\ in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Use forward slash and put entire classpath in quotes:

```
java -cp "app.jar;dynamicLib/*" my.mainclass
```

Answer (score 2):

When starting an application from a .jar file, the **command line argument -cp is ignored**. Instead, the classpath needs to be specified in the **MANIFEST.MF file's "Class-Path" attribute**. Unfortunately, **wildcards are not supported in this attribute**, so all .jar files need to be named explicitly.

Therefore, the original idea of having a "dynamicLib" directory will only work if the names of the .jar files don't change.

Alternatively you can do without the central app.jar and work with .class files instead, thus allowing you to use wildcards at the command line level.

Answer (score 1):

Classpath looks fine.

However, in order to execute a `jar` file, you have to use the `-jar` option.

```
java -cp "dynamicLib\*" -jar app.jar
```

See [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html).

-- UPDATE:

1. using the above command loads only **jar** or **JAR** files from `dynamicLib`.
2. wildcards aren't recursive: jar files under `dynamicLib\nestedDir` won't be loaded.

Comment: I tried this setup as well. No jars from `dynamicLib` are accessible.

Comment: @BlankChisui by not accessible you mean you get some exception? Which one?

Comment: a basic `ClassNotFoundException`

Comment: @yair `-cp` and `-jar` are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle's documentation

> ... Class paths to the .jar, .zip or .class files. Each classpath should end with a filename or directory depending on what you are setting the class path to:
>
> For a .jar or .zip file that contains .class files, the class path ends with the name of the .zip or .jar file.
>
> For .class files in an unnamed package, the class path ends with the directory that contains the .class files.
>
> For .class files in a named package, the class path ends with the directory that contains the "root" package (the first package in the full package name).

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/classpath.html)

This then means that `-cp dynamiclib\*` won't work. If dynamic lib contains jars, you must specify each jar in the classpath, if it contains class files then defining the folder (without the *) should be enough, unless you have classes defined in the unnamed package AKA the default package.

Comment: that is the documentation for java 5. Classpath wildcards exist:
[source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)

Comment: Was not aware that you could use wildcards, sorry about the link for Java 5 I was way too "clicky" on google to  get you a document source backing up what I was thinking it was the problem... BUT from the docs for java 6 I notice that even for windows they mention the definition as "foo/*". I've already experienced problems with \ vs / in file/directory handling in java + windows, it's something fast and easy you could try to see if it was the problem, I mean trying `dynamiclib/*` instead...